# Vertical Alignment in Absolutely Positioned Element Within Table-Row Gets Incorrect Height In Chrome

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm having an odd problem with an absolutely positioned element set to 100% height. In Firefox, the element's height becomes that of its parent (which has `position:relative`) while in Chrome, the element's height extends down past its parent.

```css
.outer
{
  display:table;
  height:150px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  background:gray;
}

.left, .right
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  background:yellow;
}

.item
{
  display:inline-block;
}

.left
{
  left:0;
}

.right
{
  right:0;
  
}

.helper
{
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.row
{
  position:relative;
  display:table-row;
  background:orange;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="helper"></div>
      <div class="item">L</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="helper"></div>
      <div class="item">R</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Text in here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Firefox, the yellow L and R divs are the same height as the orange one. In Chrome, they extend down and overlap the gray background div.

Edit: Just tested in IE and Edge, and they have the same behavior as Chrome.

Here is an image of my question in FF (left) and Chrome (right):
[image: FF vs Chrome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Chrome is computing the style of your `row` element to be `position:static`. The `row` element's parent (`outer` element) is set to `position:relative` however and this allows the absolutely positioned elements, `left` and `right`, to take 100% of its height since it is the first positioned parent element.

In my testing, this issue seems to be caused by `display:table-row` on the `row` element causing its `position` property to be computed by Chrome as `static`. Apparently, [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position) leaves this behavior up to the browser to determine which is why you're getting different behavior.

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group,
>   table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

Comment: Interesting! I worked around it by wrapping the contents of `.row` with a div with the style `position:relative; height:100%;`.